# How do I clear out user input after each use on pythonanywhere- trying to use Flask sessions

Tags: python, flask, session, session-variables, pythonanywhere

I am trying to build a simple site where a user inputs a paragraph of information (which is largely the same format each time), then I have a function that alters that paragraph to simplify it (the simplify_report function below), and spits the simplified version out for the user to have.

So far the program below works really well and I'm mostly happy with it. However, I am using pythonanywhere and the "comments" variable is global so it doesn't erase the simplified report when I reload the page (they just build up). I have looked into **Flask's sessions option**, but I just can't seem to figure out making it work with the below program (all the examples I'm seeing are for user login and I just need the site to be cleaned up/cleared out with each reload).

Alternatively, could I at least add a button the user could push to clear out the old outputs/comments? How would I go about that?

I appreciate any help!

```
#From the main file:

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from run import simplify_report

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

comments =[]

app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("page.html", comments=comments)
    newreport = simplify_report(request.form["contents"])
    comments.append(newreport)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


#Relevant section from my page.html file:
{% for comment in comments %}
            <div class="row">
                {{ comment }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

As a side note, my 'newreport' generated is all jumbled into one line and I can't seem to figure out how to format it to separate it into separate different lines. Not my main issue here though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data outside your web app on PythonAnywhere. Consider using a database for that. There is no persistency for data in the memory, as processes serving your web app could stop and start on a different server at any time.

Comment: So the problem is that the web app IS saving the data between page reloads and I don’t want it to. I want the user’s input to disappear each time the page is reloaded.

Comment: to use sessions, just store the comments for a user on their session when you generate the comments and then retrieve them in the GET part of the index code to show them to the user.